# Random Change of Colour upon changing Camera.Parameter

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am using old camera api (camera-1), and upon detecting face i am zooming the camera. So, for zooming, the camera parameter need to be updated, by by doing that, the camera colour is changing randomly.

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setZoom(newZoomValue);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Image when camera is started
[image: When camera start Image]

Image when camera is zoomed.
[image: This is hapenning, when camera parameter is changes or when i am zooming]

Can you help me how to fix this, Also Upon zooming the image is stretching, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This to help others, who have face this issue.
This issue was have because I was not setting the Picture Size of the camera. Set the these parameter on surfaceCreated() and surfaceChanged() method.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: You solution may be specific to the test device.